# Python mechanize - Submit form twice

Tags: python, forms, mechanize, form-submit

I have this website with this form that i would like to fill out. There is to forms that needs to be submitted, in the first form you've to fill out the inputs tags. When you submit that first form, it generate another form with a table showing what you just submitted, this form also have a submit button that you've to click to confirm you action. I would assume that the website uses javascript to remove the first form and then generate the next, cause the url doesn't change in that transition.

How do I submit/confirm the next form, that is generated by when the first form is submitted?

Code used to fill out the first form.

```
import mechanize

b = mechanize.Browser()
b.open("http://www.website.com/a2b.php")

b.select_form("snd")
b.find_control("t1").value = '200'  # number 1
b.find_control("t2").value = '250'  # number 2
b.find_control("t3").value = '300'  # number 3

b.submit()
```

First form

```
<form method="POST" name="snd" action="a2b.php">
 <input name="t1" value="" type="text">
 <input name="t2" value="" type="text">
 <input name="t3" value="" type="text">
 <button type="submit" value="ok" name="s1"></button>
</form>
```

Second form

```
<form method="post" action="a2b.php">
 <table> 
    Table showing the entered data, entered in previous form
</table>

 <input name="timestamp" value="1445368847" type="hidden">
 <input name="timestamp_checksum" value="JEN8mj" type="hidden">
 <input name="ckey" value="20040" type="hidden">
 <input name="id" value="39" type="hidden">
 <input name="a" value="533374" type="hidden">
 <input name="c" value="3" type="hidden">
 <button type="submit" value="ok" name="s1" id="btn_ok"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you provide us with the real URL so that the example would be reproducible for us? Thanks.

Comment: Well its a browsergame called travian, and you would need a login for that.

Comment: Okay, but what is the URL you are opening with mechanize? Thanks.

Comment: This is the url, http://tx3.travian.com/dorf1.php

Comment: Thanks for providing the URL to the form. I signed up with the site/game and tried to step through the process in my browser but didn't encounter the second form you mentioned. The first form is the login form, right? What is the second form/screen supposed to be? Thank you.

Comment: No it's not the login, that works perfectly fine, you gotta build the barracks in your town should take 5min max to build all that. And the requirement for that is:
Rally point level 1
Mainbuiling(The one in the middle) level 3
Didn't expect this to be necessary, but if it helps great.

Comment: Is there any details that is need to answer this question?

Comment: No more details needed, thanks. I haven't had time yet to try out what I was going to suggest – will do so later (but maybe @dkol's answer is already of help?).

Comment: Oh okay great, well haven't got it to work so fare, it looks pretty advance to me. Kinda hoped that mabey it could be done with a post to the url, but i don't really know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mechanize doesn't play well with javascript, try to use [Selenium Webdriver](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html) instead. It will act as browser, including JS support. You could use [Waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html) to wait for second form to appear.

Here is **an example** how you could fill your forms (I adapted the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050075/filling-out-web-form-data-using-built-in-python-modules)):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.website.com/a2b.php")

def find_by_xpath(locator):
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, locator))
    )

    return element

class FirstFormPage(object):
  def fill_form(self):
    find_by_xpath('//input[@name="t1"]').send_keys('200')
    find_by_xpath('//input[@name="t2"]').send_keys('250')
    find_by_xpath('//input[@name="t3"]').send_keys('300')

    return self # makes it so you can call .submit() after calling this function

  def submit(self):
    find_by_xpath('//input[@value = "ok"]').click()

class SecondFormPage(object):
  def fill_form(self):
    find_by_xpath('//input[@name="timestamp"]').send_keys('1445368847')
    find_by_xpath('//input[@name="timestamp_checksum"]').send_keys('JEN8mj')
    find_by_xpath('//input[@name="ckey"]').send_keys('20040')
    find_by_xpath('//input[@name="id"]').send_keys('39')
    find_by_xpath('//input[@name="a"]').send_keys('533374')
    find_by_xpath('//input[@name="c"]').send_keys('3')

    return self # makes it so you can call .submit() after calling this function

  def submit(self):
    find_by_xpath('//input[@value = "ok"]').click()

FirstFormPage().fill_form().submit()
SecondFormPage().fill_form().submit()
driver.quit() # closes the webbrowser
```

Adapt this to your needs!

Comment: Looks like an option, though i can't quite get it to work proberly. I need to login on the page aswell, before getting to the 2 forms. Also in the secondform is just a confirm form, so no values have to be changed.

Comment: There is also [Selenium IDE](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) which allows you to record browser actions and then reproduce it and even edit it programmaticaly later, might be easier to understand.